# Navigate in gvim like in most

Tags: vim

I'd like to use gvim to view files with long lines. It's a table, so I'm not wrapping the lines. 
Is this possible to configure gvim so arrows navigation will be like in "most" tool? Arrow key will move the whole screen 1 character lef/right/top/bottom? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want.

```
set nocompatible
set nowrap
set virtualedit=all

nnoremap <Left> zh
nnoremap <Right> zl
nnoremap <Up> <C-y>
nnoremap <Down> <C-e>
```

If you want the same behavior in insert mode, add the same mappings again as a second set, but use `inoremap` instead of `nnoremap`.

The `virtualedit` setting will allow the cursor to move beyond the end of the line and continue on as if the line had infinite whitespace to the right.

**NOTE**: `virtualedit` is only available if Vim was compiled with that feature. You can check with `:version`. If this feature is available, you should see a `+` next to it, e.g. `+virtualedit`.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, exactly what I searched for. Just one small issue - when I move to the right, it moves the text as long as the cursor doesn't reach last character on the current line, so if the cursor is not on the longest line - you can't reach the right-most text. So, sometimes, I need to move up/dn the cursor, to place it on the current line.

Comment: @alg See updated answer. You can fix that with `virtualedit` (if your copy of Vim has it available).